# Could not find active fragment with index -1

Tags: android

Activity fragment manager problem When change orientation:

> > ```
> > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find active fragment with index -1
> >                                                                 at
> > ```
> >
> > android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:3026)
> >                                                                         at
> >     android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1446)
> >                                                                         at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1380)
> >                                                                         at
> >     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
> >                                                                      at
> >     com.motors.mobile.core.v2.DaggerIncludeBaseActivity.onCreate(DaggerIncludeBaseActivity.java:26)

**Follow my code :**

```
@Override
protected void tabletPortraitInit(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.tabletPortraitInit(savedInstanceState);
    openSubFragment();
}

@Override
protected void tableLandscapeInit(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.tableLandscapeInit(savedInstanceState);
    openSubFragment();
}

protected void openSubFragment() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra(CAR_DETAIL_KEY);
    fragment = new BuyDetailFragment();
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BuyDetailFragment.TAG) != null)
        fragment = (BuyDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BuyDetailFragment.TAG);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    menuClickListener = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flMain, fragment, BuyDetailFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
    // init toolbar items
    View tbView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.items_detail_menu_layout, toolbar.findViewById(R.id.container), true);
    phone = tbView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    message = tbView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    link = tbView.findViewById(R.id.notifications);
    site = tbView.findViewById(R.id.site);
    shortlistView = tbView.findViewById(R.id.wishListMenu);
    phone.setOnClickListener((e) -> menuClickListener.clickPhone());
    message.setOnClickListener((e) -> menuClickListener.clickMessage());
    link.setOnClickListener((e) -> menuClickListener.clickNotifications());
    site.setOnClickListener((e) -> menuClickListener.clickSite());
    shortlistView.setOnClickListener((e) -> menuClickListener.clickShortlist());
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.vector_heart);
    drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    shortlistView.changeIcon(drawable);
}

        There is no my baseActivity
```

Comment: add your code,please

Answer (score 3):

Does your fragment have `setRetainInstance(true)`? If so, that may be causing you an issue here, especially if you are using a fragment apart of FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen with a combination of [dismissAllowingStateLoss](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#dismissAllowingStateLoss()) after [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [retainInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)).

See this [helpful example with steps to reproduce](https://exceptionshub.com/could-not-find-active-fragment-with-index-1-when-using-dialogfragment.html) (that site does not allow commenting, but it helped me diagnose the issue)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open page and show dialog fragment with retainInstance = true
2. Background app, onSaveInstanceState is called
3. dismiss dialog in an async task via dismissAllowingStateLoss
4. perform configuration change, for example by changing language or orientation
5. open app
6. crash "Unable to start activity... java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find active fragment with index -1"

Under the scenes what's going on is that [FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#3025) now has an active fragment with an index of -1 because dismissAllowingStateLoss removes the fragment from the backstack, BUT, it is still part of nonConfigFragments because the commit part of dismissAllowingStateLoss was ignored as it was called after onSaveInstanceState.

To fix this will require one of:

1. not using retainInstanceState on Dialogs that can be dismissed via dismissAllowStateLoss, or
2. not calling dismiss after state loss

and implementing the desired behavior in a different way.