# IllegalStateException in FragmentManager -> restoreAllState(): Could not find active fragment with index -1

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use AppCompatActivity with Fragments, and most likely when the screen change orientation, the following error occurs:

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException Could not find active fragment with index -1

The error occurs only in 0.1% of users. On this activity I show extended `DialogFragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)`. I could not reproduce the problem myself!

*Maybe you know how to avoid this error?*

**Stack trace:**

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:3047)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState (FragmentController.java:152)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:330)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:84)
(see code 2) com.example.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java:76)
(see code 1) com.example.authorization.AuthorizationActivity.onCreate (AuthorizationActivity.java:39)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6772)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2715)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2823)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4655)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1551)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6349)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:893)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

**Code 1 (from AuthorizationActivity.java):**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // THIS LINE

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authorization);

    db_user = new UserDatabase(this);
    db_wedding = new WeddingDatabase(this);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.authorization_container, new AuthorizationMainFragment()).commit();
    }

    boolean show = getPreferences().getBoolean(SettingsWeddingFragment.KEY_RESTORE_FILL, false);
    if (show) {
        db_wedding.showFillDefaultDataMessage(runnable);
    }
}
```

**Code 2 (from BaseActivity.java):**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // THIS LINE

    Helper.setBootTimeDifference(this);

    resetTitle();

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Alert.newInstance(this);

    if (!(BaseActivity.this instanceof SplashActivity)) {
        BaseActivity.incAdCounter();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        if (isVisible()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.authorization_container, new AuthorizationMainFragment()).commit();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with a combination of [dismissAllowingStateLoss](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) after [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [retainInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)).

See [answer to "Could not find active fragment with index -1"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66119253/1596587)